# How to cut long labels in Matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib

I would like to cut long labels, so that only the first 4 letters are displayed, without changing the values in the original data frame.

Example:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sn

np.random.seed(89)

# Toy Dataset
d = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,3, size=(100, 1)), columns=['var'])
d['var'] = (np.where(d['var'] == 1,'Long loooooong loooooong text',d['var']))

# Plot
f, axes = plt.subplots()
sns.countplot(y='var', data=d, orient='h');
```

**Current output**:
[image]

**Desirable output:**

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is best solved by supplying the data in short form already.

```
df2 = d.copy()
df2["var"] = df2["var"].apply(lambda x: x[:4])

# Plot
f, axes = plt.subplots()
sns.countplot(y='var', data=df2, orient='h');
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I will provide a slightly general solution: Iterate through your y-tick labels and then create a list of new labels, which stores only up to 4 characters if any label has more than 4 characters. Finally, assign this new list of labels as the y-ticks

```
# Plot
f, axes = plt.subplots()
ax = sns.countplot(y='var', data=d, orient='h');

new_labels = []

for i in ax.yaxis.get_ticklabels():
    label = i.get_text()
    if len(label) > 4:
        new_labels.append(label[0:4])
    else:    
        new_labels.append(label)

ax.yaxis.set_ticklabels(new_labels)
```

Or you can create the new labels in a single line using list comprehension as

```
new_labels = [i.get_text()[0:4] if len(i.get_text()) > 4 else i.get_text() 
              for i in ax.yaxis.get_ticklabels()]
```

[image]

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

np.random.seed(89)

# Toy Dataset
d = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,3, size=(100, 1)), columns=['var'])
d['var'] = (np.where(d['var'] == 1,'Long loooooong loooooong text'[:4],d['var']))

# Plot
f, axes = plt.subplots()
sns.countplot(y='var', data=d, orient='h');
```

to get the 4 first letters of a string :

```
first_four_letters = your_string[:4]
```

Comment: While this answers the question, I still don't see the reason why first put a big string and then take first four characters. This long string has no other purpose in the code and is redundant. So why use it by hard coding